# ¿Como corregir: 'Creating default object from empty value' en Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

En la blade tengo este codigo:

```
@foreach
<tr id="{{$employee->id}}">
<td class="visibleemployee">
<form action="{{route('admin.employees.cambiarVisible',$employee->id)}}">
  <button type="button" id="buttonchangevisible" data-id="{{$employee->id}}">
    @if ($employee->public == '1')
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee" class="cambiarsiporno"></i>
    @else
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee"></i>
    @endif
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
 </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Al hacer clic en el botón, se ejecuta esta función con Ajax:

```
$("#buttonchangevisible").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var id = button.data('id');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'employee/cambiarVisible/' + id,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: formData,
            success: function() {
                location.reload();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Que llama al siguiente método del controlador:

```
public function cambiarVisible(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $employee = Worker::findOrFail($id);
        $employee->public = ($employee->public == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        $employee->save();
    }
```

Archivo rutas: (todo va dentro de un group que le añade el prefijo admin).

```
  Route::put('employee/cambiarVisible/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@cambiarVisible', 'as' => 'admin.employees.cambiarVisible']);
```

El error citado en el titulo esta solucionado, ahora al hacer clic en la primera fila hace la llamada correctamente pero no hace el update del campo.
Al hacer clic en cualquier otra fila directamente no hace la llamada.

Comment: ¿ya fue solucionada la pregunta?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el problema ya fue solucionado.

Comment: @toledano ¿qué sentido tiene cerrar un problema porque ya fue solucionado? En base a eso, cerraríamos todas las preguntas que tienen respuesta aceptada :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está mal puesta la ruta del código Ajax, no puedes usar rutas de laravel en js ('employee/cambiarVisible/**{id}**').
Si haces un "dd($id)" en el controlador veras que no te llega el valor, por lo que tendras que pasarlo por POST/PUT

Te dejo un ejemplo con el tipo delete (para PUT seria solo cambiar el _method de tipo delete a put)

```
function eliminar(ruta) {
 $.ajax({
                url: ruta,
                data: {'_method': 'delete', '_token': '{{Session::token()}}'},
                type: 'post',
                success: function () {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    swal({
                        title: '¡¡ERROR!!',
                        type: 'error',
                        text: "No se pudo eliminar",
                        confirmButtonText: 'CONTINUAR',
                        showCancelButton: false
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Eso ya esta solucionado, si puedes revisa la pregunta :)

Comment: Pon como definiste la ruta, porque tal y como lo  tienes ahora creo que la habrás definido mal, tienes que añadirle una interrogación para hacerlo opcional "employee/cambiarVisible/{id?}'". Tambien decirte que el metodo PUT no lo aceptan los navegadores, tienes que pasar una variable llamada "_method" con valor PUT y mandar por POST

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @ManuelRobles no quiero que sea opcional ya que siempre que cambie el estado de publico o no, voy a pasar el ID. Podrías modificar el codigo con lo ultimo que me comentas? Gracias

Comment: Te añado un ejemplo de PUT que tengo a mano

Comment: Ya esta funcionando, gracias de todos modos :)